# Transforming a collection to a map in Elixir

Tags: elixir

If I've got a collection of the form:

```
[{key, value}, {key, value2}, {key2, value3}]
```

how do I transform it to a map of the form

```
%{key => [value, value2], key2 => [value3]}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing with [`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Map.html#update/4) would be a good fit:

```rb
[{:key, :value}, {:key, :value2}, {:key2, :value3}]
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {k, v}, acc ->
  Map.update(acc, k, [v], fn l -> [v | l] end)
end)
#⇒ %{key: [:value2, :value], key2: [:value3]}
```

To preserve an order of lists, map to `{k, Enum.reverse(n)}` afterwards.

```rb
[{:key, :value}, {:key, :value2}, {:key2, :value3}]
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {k, v}, acc ->
  Map.update(acc, k, [v], fn l -> [v | l] end)
end)
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, Enum.reverse(v)} end)
#⇒ %{key: [:value, :value2], key2: [:value3]}
```

---

Another option would be [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#group_by/3)

```rb
[{:key, :value}, {:key, :value2}, {:key2, :value3}]
|> Enum.group_by(&elem(&1, 0))
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, Keyword.values(v)} end)
|> Enum.into(%{})
#⇒ %{key: [:value, :value2], key2: [:value3]}
```

or, with a mapper:

```rb
[{:key, :value}, {:key, :value2}, {:key2, :value3}]
|> Enum.group_by(&elem(&1, 0), &elem(&1, 1)) 
#⇒ %{key: [:value, :value2], key2: [:value3]}
```